# macOS Entitlements for Removable Media

Tags: macos, appstore-sandbox, entitlements, removable-storage

When sandboxing an app for the macOS app store, is it possible to allow for read/write access to removable media (SD Cards specifically)? So far, I've haven't been able to find an entitlement that would work. The Windows Store does have an entitlement for removable media so I'm hoping I'm just missing something on the Apple side.

Here is the current entitlements content:

Our current Entitlements file has this set for the dictionary:

```
<dict>
  <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
  <true/>
  <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
  <true/>
  <key>com.apple.security.device.usb</key>
  <true/>
  <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
  <true/>
  <key>com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Here is the exception being thrown:
[image]

Comment: Are you accessing it via a filesystem mount, or a lower-level API?  I imagine that `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write ` is good for the former, and perhaps `com.apple.security.device.usb` for the latter.  What did you try?

Comment: I've added the details of the Entitlements to the original post. Basically, we are trying to access the SD card through the .NET Mono build with the error `Access to the path ‘/Volumes/NO NAME/Garmin’ is denied.`

Comment: Did the user select this file?

Comment: We were attempting to do this without using the NSOpenPanel and NSSavePanel for a more smooth user experience, but it looks like it will be the only way to allow this to happen. I'll post back here with results soon. Thanks @Ssswift!

Comment: We are able to get this to work when having the users specify specific files, but not at a folder level. We are going to keep experimenting a bit, but we may go another route and avoid the store sandboxing. Thank you helping with the direction of research @Ssswift.

Comment: The end result is that we are going to deploy the osx app outside the mac store. It's unfortunate because I'd love to leverage sandboxing. Hopefully a "removable media" option would be added sometime in the future.

Comment: Hmm, that seems strange.  IME, user selection of a folder also authorizes all items in it.

Comment: It is entirely possible I'm doing something incorrectly. It seems after I select the folder I still get access denied for subsequent writes. I'll run through the branch again and try to strip out all other activity in case I'm introducing something strange elsewhere.