# Installing and triggerring macOS app from an install4j installer

Tags: install4j

I have use-case where my java app needs to access USBMSC (USB mass storage class) devices through serial port using a third party dylib. However, since macOS mojave (10.13) the privileged helper tool script written in shell-script stopped working. To address that we create a swift app that can set the correct permissions of the the device without using a shell-script and that is working as expected. I now want to create a re-distributable that can install both, the executable jar and the macOS app, because we do not want users to run separate installers and make their experience any worse.

I have tried bundling the app along with other files and using **Run executable or batch file** action without any success.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**: After running few tests using trial and error (Yup, I could not find the installation log files on mac), the real root cause was found. The helper application is missing "Removable media" permissions, which should be inherited from the parent application, as the helper application is bundled within the parent java app bundle.
I was able to execute the helper macOS app from the parent app contents only after giving the permission to access the "Removable media" from `System Preferences->Security & Privacy->Files and Folders` to the parent app.

Now the question really changes to: How can I acquire the "Removable media" permission during the installation itself before executing the helper macOS  app through **Run executable or batch file** action?

Comment: What is the result of the "Run executable or batch file" in the log file? Is it set to execute with maximum available privileges? Do you have a "Request privileges" action in the project and is it executed for all users on macOS?

Comment: Please check the EDIT

Comment: Yes, @IngoKegel, The app is set to execute with maximum available privileges and I do have "Request privileges" action as the first and only item in my Startup group.

Comment: I would guess that there are entitlements that could be set in the "macOS entitlements file" property of the installer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702911/macos-entitlements-for-removable-media for an inconclusive discussion.

Comment: @IngoKegel, Is there any way to get these entitlements through install4j installer? The java app anyways will need it as the functionality of the app requires connecting to a mass storage class devices through USB

Comment: With the property I have mentioned above you can set entitlements for the installer. The launchers have their own entitlement setting in the launcher wizard. However, I don't know what entitlements are required and if there are such entitlements at all.